# datetimeformatter doesnt return the expected output of month value in greek locale

Tags: java, android, datetime-format

I am building a calendar so for every month i show i want in the top to show the month following by the year like: "November 2023", the application is in greek so in greek the same result I expect is: "Νοέμβριος 2023". I made a method and the output i get is "Νοεμβρίου 2023", this output in english is like November's 2023, in free translation. I know that maybe a solution is via an MapList that based the wrong value I give the true I want. I want to know if there is another way faster, because i cant find any built in way.

I think for greek programmers maybe is easier to help me, but appreciate any help by every programmer that had similar problem in his native language.

```
   public static String monthYearFromDate(LocalDate date) 
    {
        Locale greekLocale = new Locale("el");
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                .appendPattern("MMMM yyyy")
                .toFormatter(greekLocale);

        return date.format(formatter);
    }
```

[image: This is the wrong format.]

Comment: So your problem is that `ε` is displayed (instead of `έ`) ?

Comment: @Abra No, read again please carefully because I describe my problem. It's about the meaning of the words, I want November but I get November's.

Comment: have you tried `"LLLL yyyy"` ? From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html): "Pattern letters 'L', 'c', and 'q' specify the stand-alone form of the text styles." (and I would even prefer `"LLLL uuuu"` {for the year, see documentation} )

Comment: @user85421 unfortunately for me no, I get this result https://ibb.co/Ykb7nYb

Comment: @user85421 I don't know your code seems right, when i put as format "LLLL yyyy" I get back "10 2023" and when I put "MMMM yyyy" I get back text in the wrong way as I told in my question's headline.

Answer (score 2):

this code will work for you :

```
public static String monthYearFromDate(LocalDate date)
{
    Locale greekLocale = new Locale("el","GR");
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .appendPattern("LLLL yyyy")
            .toFormatter(greekLocale);
    return formatter.format(date);
}
```

If you got confused I would suggest you to read JDK docs

Comment: I forgot to mentioned this format, I get this result with "LLLL yyyy" https://ibb.co/Ykb7nYb

Comment: It prints for me : Νοέμβριος 2023 with this input : LocalDate.of(2023, 11,1))
somewhere you are getting month int value

Comment: the date variable that is parametrized in method coming through LocalDate.now(), and then for next and previous month date.plusMonths(1); and minusMonths(1); . Is it maybe a reason that I get wrong result?

Comment: I think plus/minus operation is causing problem

Comment: and LocalDate.now() also maybe ?

Comment: No it works properly

Comment: It indeed [works properly](https://ideone.com/nfRuMP).

Comment: Also my problem is in Android Programming. Android has grandle declaration and Java properties to be modyfied. You provide me just Java code without taking into account these rules. Show me the same code in an android studio project to be accurate.